# About proper segment of total order set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $(A,≤)$ be a well-ordered set.

Then for each proper segment S of A, there exists an element $x\in A$ such that $S=A_x$, where $A_x=\{a\in A\ | \ a<x\}$

If we let $x=$min$(A\setminus S)$, we can prove this.

But I wonder how to prove that there exists a segment $S'$ such that $S'\neq\{a\in A \ |\ a<x\}$ for all $x\in A$ if $(A,≤)$ is just a total order set.

There is an example; ($\mathbb{R},≤$) is a total order set and $(-\infty,0]$ is a segment of ($\mathbb{R},≤$)

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Let $(S, \leq)$ be a total order, and let $W \subseteq S$ be a non-empty set. Then $S' = ${$x \in S | \forall w \in W, x < w$} is a proper initial segment of $S$. If there is some $a \in S$ such that $S' = ${$x \in S : x < a$}, then $a$ will be the least element of $W$. Consequently, when $S$ is not a well order, it suffices to find some $W$ which is non-empty and doesn't possess a least element. In your special case of $(\mathbb{R}, \leq)$, the set $W$ was $(0, \infty)$.